# Finding normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X\sim N(4,16)$. $P(X>{-x}_{0})=0.95$ , find ${x}_{0}$.

If $X\sim N(4,16)$ then $\mu =4$ and $\sigma =4$ then

$P(X>{-x}_{0})=P(Z>\frac{-{x}_{0}-4}{4})=P(Z>0)-P(0<Z<\frac{-{x}_{0}-4}{4})=0.5-P(0<Z<\frac{-{x}_{0}-4}{4})=0.95$

$\Rightarrow P(0<Z<\frac{-{x}_{0}-4}{4})=-0.45$

But I'm stuck here. Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If $X\sim N(4,16)$, then

$$P(X>-x_0)=P\left( Z>\dfrac{-x_0-4}{4}\right) =1-P\left( Z<\dfrac{-x_0-4}{4}\right) =0.95$$

Then,

$$P\left( Z<\dfrac{-x_0-4}{4}\right) =1-0.95=0.05$$

Now we locate in the normal distribution table the value $0.05$ and observe that it corresponds to $P(Z<-1.64485)$:

$$\dfrac{-x_0-4}{4}=-1.64485\Rightarrow x_0=2.5794$$

Comment: You can’t say that $P(Z<0.13)=0.05$, because $P(Z<0.13) = 0.552$.

Comment: No in the given table 0.0517

Comment: Then the table is wrong. If $Z\sim N(0,1)$, then $P(Z<0.13)=0.5517$.

Comment: I share the table with you , check it out

Comment: This table gives the probabilities of $0<Z<z$, for positive $z$: $P(0<Z<0.13)=0.0557$.